# CdnFallbackExpression in ScriptBundle()

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I tried to use `ScriptBundle` with external reference:

```
var signalRPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.1.min.js";
var signalRBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/participationSignalRLayout", signalRPath);
signalRBundle.CdnFallbackExpression = "$.connection";
bundles.Add(signalRBundle);`
```

After that I tried to use return value in my view in script section:

```
var hub = $.connection.rateHub;
```

And I have an `undefined` value in `$.connection`, but when I use standard script connection:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

And commented out bundle section I have correct value in `$.connection`. I guess I do not have the correct CdnFallbackExpression. What value must be entered in CdnFallbackExpression to get correct value from js lib in 
`$.connection`?